# How to draw a dotted line in a video using open cv

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I tried this code to draw an animated dot on a video

```
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import time

vs = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/intercept.mp4')    
pts = deque(maxlen=64) #buffer size

# keep looping
while True:
    ret,frame = vs.read()

    if frame is None:
        break
    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    for i in range(10,260,20):
        time.sleep(0.5)     #To visualise dots one by one
        cv2.circle(frame,(i, i),10, (0,0,255), -1) #draw circle
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)     #show output image
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.release()
```

But the entire animation takes place over a single frame rather than being continous over consecutive frames. Also I want to add a certain element of jitter/randomness to the red ball/circle.
How can I achieve both ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC just want to be able to draw a wiggly line acroos the video. Entering from left and exiting through right.

Comment: Please try and improve your question. It is not very clear what you are trying to do and people don't like to waste their time guessing. You mention movement and a video but your code shows a still image? You mention wavy lines like snakes but your code draws a straight line? I don't believe anyone can sensibly help you till you improve your question.

Comment: @MarkSetchell improved the code further

Comment: @AMC improved the code further, based upon what I just tried

Answer (score 1):

Ahh solved it by tweaking the sleep timer, and skipping the frames

```
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import time

vs = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/intercept.mp4')
pts = deque(maxlen=64) #buffer size

i=0
ct=0
# keep looping
while True:
    ret,frame = vs.read()
    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    i+=2
    ct+=10
    #for i in range(10,260,20):
        #time.sleep(0.5)     #To visualise dots one by one
    if ct%10==0:
        cv2.circle(frame,(i, i),10, (0,0,255), -1) #draw circle
        #cv2.imshow('frame',frame)     #show output image
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.release()
```